# If $x>5$ is an integer then $3^xx>20(2x^2+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Direct question - If $x>5$ is an integer then $$3^xx > 20(2x^2+1)$$ This question is from an old set of course notes from the UF taught in 1994. This is one of the problems I got wrong on a quiz. My first instinct is to take logarithms but that almost always goes nowhere directly.

Comment: Show it by induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to prove a slightly stronger inequality than the one requested.  In this case, we can begin by rewriting the inequality to be proved as

$$3^x\gt 40x+{20\over x}$$

for $x\gt5$.  Now note that for $x\gt5$, we have $4\gt{20\over x}$  So it suffices to prove

$$3^x\gt40x+4$$

for $x\gt5$.  Now writing $x=u+5$ with $u\gt0$, we see this is equivalent to proving

$$3^u\gt{1\over3^5}(40(u+5)+4)={204\over243}+{40\over243}u$$

and this follows from

$$3^u\gt e^u\gt1+u\gt{204\over243}+{40\over243}u$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is true when $x=6$.

Assume it is true for $x$.

Note that $$60(2x^2+1) \ge 20(2(x+1)^2+1)$$ Simplifies to $$80x^2-80 \ge 0$$ Which is true if $x \ge 5$.

Now, note that $$3^{x+1} \times (x+1) > 3^{x+1} \times x  >60(2x^2+1)> 20(2(x+1)^2+1)$$

Thus it is true for $x+1$.

We are done.

Comment: How does your argument $3^{x+1}x>60(2x^2+1)$ follow?

Comment: That is the induction step? You are assuming it is true for all $x$ and considering the case $x+1$ ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez No, not all $x$. Just $x$.